# Wie kann ich "growth mindset" am besten übersetzen?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Ich will meinem Kind [growth mindset](https://sivers.org/mindset) beibringen. Dafür suche ich einen passenden deutschen Ausdruck, aber alles, was mir bislang eingefallen ist, ist zu lang oder gefällt mir nicht:

- Wachstumsdenkweise
- Entwicklungsmentalität
- Entwicklungsorientierte Glaubenssätze
- Entwicklungsorientierte Einstellung (zum Leben)
- Entwicklungsorientiertes Paradigma

Gibt es bessere (kürzere oder prägnantere) Übersetzungen?

Comment: "wachstumsorientierte Haltung" (aber halte ich auch nicht für eine übermäßig kindgeeignete Umschreibung)

Comment: Wille zum Wachsen.

Comment: Deinem Kind? Die Begriffe klingen eher wie aus einem Lebenslauf.

Comment: "Wille zum Wachsen" ist Quatsch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[In diesem Artikel](http://familie.ulrike-grossmann.de/2013/09/mindset-carol-dweck/) wird es mit *dynamisches Selbstbild* übersetzt. Das *fixed mindset* ist dann das *statische Selbstbild*.

Die Übersetzung wirkt auf den ersten Blick sehr frei, aber rührt daher, dass sich das Thema ja letztlich mit dem *self-image* beschäftigt.

Das Buch *Mindset* von Carol Dweck heißt in der deutschen Version übrigens auch schlicht *[Selbstbild](https://www.amazon.de/Selbstbild-Denken-Erfolge-Niederlagen-bewirkt/dp/3492252273?ie=UTF8&*Version*=1&*entries*=0)*.

Answer (score -1):

Mindset = Gedankenwelt.

Fixed Mindset = festgefahrene Gedankenwelt.

Groth Mindset = wachsende Gedankenwelt

Comment: Wachsende Gedankenwelt wäre aber ein growing mindset, oder? Gemeint ist aber eine wachstumsorientierte.